# Derivation of constrained Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, constrained-dynamics

I've seen the formula for a constrained Lagrangian several times and while its somewhat intuitive, coming up with a rigorous proof has stumped me. I think I might misunderstand part of it and hope to find some help.

When considering Lagrange multipliers, I think it makes sense that if we say for all $\delta \vec x$ such that $$\delta \vec x\cdot \nabla h|_x=0\rightarrow \delta \vec x \cdot \nabla f|_x=0,$$ then $\nabla f=\lambda \nabla h$ at such $x$ for some $\lambda$, we see this as the condition described asserts both $f,h$ are orthogonal to the tangent plane described by the surface $h(\vec x)=0$.

Now if we assume a particle is bound to the surface $h(\vec q(t))=0$, we look at the action: $$S=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}L(\vec {q(t)}, \vec{\dot q(t)},t)dt.$$ We then apply least action under the condition our variation is constrained to the surface as well, taking a small variation leaves us with $\vec{ \delta q(t)}\cdot \nabla h=0$. Going through the usual steps of E-L we also get $$\delta S=\int_{t_1}^{t_2}(L_{\vec q}-\dot{L_{\vec{\dot q}}})\cdot \vec{\delta q(t)}dt=0$$ for a sufficient $q(t)$. Now it is unclear to me whether or not we are able to pull out the integrand to say $$\delta{\vec q} \cdot \nabla h = 0 \rightarrow  (L_{\vec q}-\dot{L_{\vec{\dot q}}}) \cdot \vec{\delta q(t)}=0$$ since our $\delta \vec q$ is now restricted to satisfying $\delta \vec q \cdot \nabla h=0$.

I possibly jumped a few steps above but I think the confusion is understandable--this isn't a clear cut "maximize $f$ subject to $h$" type of problem, its a little more involved and hard to see how to approach it. Any help would towards deriving the $L_{\vec q}-\dot{L_{\vec{\dot q}}}=\lambda (t) \nabla h$ equation would be very much appreciated

Comment: @Qmechanic I don’t see it. Were trying to maximize/extremize int((L_q-L’_q’)•delta_qdt) for all path variations delta_q under h(x)=0 right? If we add lambda*h to the end of there and take the gradient we don’t recover the last equation I put in my post, I don’t see how the integral gets dealt with

Comment: @Qmechanic can we get rid of the integral by thinking about the case where we vary the time interval? Every new increment of time leaves the integral unchanged, showing us that at every instant the integrand must be 0, allowing me to use the ”condition” for applying Lagrange multipliers I described

Comment: Crossposted from: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4726139/11127

Comment: @Qmechanic not sure if that's a "gotcha" or a reference for other viewers but I got no answers, posting here made more sense though I originally thought the math forum would give me the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, here is an heuristic argument via discretization:

1. In the context of a static system with finitely many variables $q^j$, $j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, first generalize the [Lagrange multiplier method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) to finitely many constraints $f_a=0$ and finitely many Lagrange multipliers $\lambda^a$, where $a\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$.
2. Next generalize to a dynamical system where the variables $q^j(t_{\alpha})$ and $\lambda^a(t_{\alpha})$ now depend on discrete time $t_{\alpha}$, where $\alpha\in\{1,\ldots,N\}$. Kinematics are implemented with the help of [difference quotients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_quotient).
3. Finally take the continuum limit with a continuous time variable $t$. A sum over discrete time gets replaced by an integral over time.

Comment: I was able to get my way to work by doing what I should've done at first, express $\delta q_n$ in terms of the other variations and make the substitution in the integral, then use the fundamental theorem of calculus of variations to achieve the conclusion without needing to rely on heuristics